# Notifications from Team City nuget feed in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, teamcity, nuget

I am using visual studio 2013 and have configured my Team City to publish a nuGet feed. I have added that feed to my nuGet sources in Visual Studio and then downloaded a package, Everything worked as expected. The issue is that since I installed the package I have not been notified of any updates for that package from Team City. When I open the package manager and look at the package the Update button is there so Visual Studio knows there is an update. Is there a way to get Team Cities nuGet feed to add notifications to the notifications well or anywhere in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a nuget thing and not directly related to TeamCity.  The official nuget feed behaves this way as well.  To enable the behavior you desire do the following..

1) Download [Nuget.exe](http://nuget.org/nuget.exe) Command Line Utility
2) Add Nuget.exe to your path, or store it in your Solution someplace
3) Add a prebuild event to your project

```
Nuget.exe update ..\..\Packages.config
```

4) Profit

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication8, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 3/24/2014 3:00:00 PM.
1>PreBuildEvent:
1>  C:\Nuget.exe update ..\..\Packages.config
1>  Looking for installed packages in '..\..\..\packages'.
1>  Updating 'ConsoleApplication8'...
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
```

According to the docs you can also target a .csproj file or a .sln (havent tried that though)

Comment: Thank you for that! I was totally barking up the wrong tree.